# Is it possible to parse Ruby instance variables in coffee script asset files?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am attempting to pass in instance variable from my rails app to the associated coffeescript file, but it currently does not seem to be parsing. What am I missing?

**locations.js.coffee.erb**

```
$.ajax
  url: "/map_groups/<%= @id %>.json"
  type: "get"
  dataType: "json"
  async: false
  success: (response) ->
    exports.response = response
```

**locations_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @id = (params[:id]) ? params[:id] : 1
  @locations = Location.all
end
```

But this is the error showing up in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/map_groups/.json
```

Is there something I can do to get the instance variable to parse?

**note:**

I know the variable exists, because it is being passed to the view.

**edit: What I am trying to do**

Most of my data is being sent via JSON, and I have created a custom route in order to let the coffeescript know what json data to pull:

```
get "/locations/map-group/:id", controller: :locations, action: :index, as: :map_group
```

If you refer back to my controller - you will see that if a user visits plain old `/locations` the ID defaults to 1. Otherwise, the id is whatever gets specified in the URL. The coffeescript file needs to pull data relevant to that ID through an AJAX call. How can I tell the coffeescript what that ID is?

Comment: When working with AJAX the best approach IMO is to print a JSON object to the page and use that in JavaScript, instead of putting code inline. Not sure what the issue is though...

Comment: Pass things simply as _data_. Go via _JSON_. Build your more complicated things from the _data_.

Comment: @PaulS. That's what I am doing, but I need to pull the ID of the JSON file for coffeescript to grab from the URL.

Comment: @anwyatt: That ID is data as well. What I suggest is printing out a JSON object containing the ID in a script tag, then build your url string from there.

Comment: @elclanrs I don't think i fully understand your instructions. Can you post an answer with more information?

Comment: I'm not very experienced in Ruby, but in PHP I'd do this `<script>var data = <?= json_encode(['id'=>123]) ?></script>`. Then build your url like `url: '/map_groups/'+ data.id`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## What I would do instead

I would strongly recommend not using Ruby instance variables to generate CoffeeScript, if you can avoid it. I would suggest using a library like this to handle the use case you are considering:

https://github.com/railsware/js-routes

```
# Configuration above will create a nice javascript file with Routes object that has all the rails routes available:

Routes.users_path() // => "/users"
Routes.user_path(1) // => "/users/1"
Routes.user_path(1, {format: 'json'}) // => "/users/1.json"
Routes.new_user_project_path(1, {format: 'json'}) // => "/users/1/projects/new.json"
Routes.user_project_path(1,2, {q: 'hello', custom: true}) // => "/users/1/projects/2?q=hello&custom=true"
Routes.user_project_path(1,2, {hello: ['world', 'mars']}) // => "/users/1/projects/2?hello%5B%5D=world&hello%5B%5D=mars"
```

This plus HTML5 `data-*` tags would help you pass along the identifying information you need in your JavaScript:

http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

For example:

```
<div id="my_awesome_location" data-location-id="<%= @location.id %>">...</div>
```

Then load your ajax like this:

```
id = $("#my_awesome_location").data('location-id')

$.ajax
  url: Routes.map_group_path(id) #=> "/map_groups/#{id}.json"
  type: "get"
  dataType: "json"
  ...
```

## How to do it anyways

However, if you absolutely must use ERB style tags in your CoffeeScript, you can do it by using `coffee.erb` file extension:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

> 2.3.3 JavaScript/CoffeeScript and ERB
>
> If you add an erb extension to a JavaScript asset, making it something such as application.js.erb, then you can use the asset_path helper in your JavaScript code:

```
$('#logo').attr({
  src: "<%= asset_path('logo.png') %>"
});
```

> This writes the path to the particular asset being referenced.
>
> Similarly, you can use the asset_path helper in CoffeeScript files with erb extension (e.g., application.js.coffee.erb):

```
$('#logo').attr src: "<%= asset_path('logo.png') %>"
```

## Why you probably don't want to do it that way

The reason I would suggest using the above library versus straight ERB is the tight coupling that you have between controller/views and assets.

It also means that you have to have your who entire app pre-loaded before you can do asset compilation, so you'll have that bite you in the behind if you try to deploy to a PaaS like Heroku.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

> The app’s config vars are not available in the environment during the slug compilation process. Because the app must be loaded to run the assets:precompile task, any initialization code that requires existence of config vars should gracefully handle the nil case.

Basically, if you change your controller even a little bit, you risk breaking your assets. It's best to keep them as separate units and to introduce a mediation layer that handles what you are trying to solve.

Comment: I don't know that your library is relevant to my exact use-case. However, I have added some additional information to my question. Can you help me solve my issue without the coupling issues?

Comment: ah - just saw the data-attribute link. Just kidding. I think this will work. standby.

Answer (score 1):

As Farley Knight says, yes you can, but please don't for the reasons he stated.

What has worked best for me is hidden fields with the data inside my ERB file. Then since you're using JQuery, just use `idField.val()` in your url for the `$.ajax` call.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I ended up using Farley Knight's data-attribute suggestion (which is really cool!). Make sure you check that out. I seriously appreciate your input though, and your answer was going to be what I tried next (and it would have worked too).